# Stop Grid Coordinates Overlapping in Print Layout

Tags: qgis, grids-graticules, atlas, mapping

I have created some data driven pages in the print layout (controlled by atlas) using QGIS 3.4. The grid spacing is set to a fixed interval (20m). This works fine until one of the pages is located in such a way that means the Y coordinate label overlaps the X. Is there a setting that will stop a coordinate printing if it overlaps another?

[image: Map coordinates overlapping for certain data driven pages]

Comment: Which software?

Comment: Good point, I'm using QGIS. Question edited.

Comment: That might be worth making a feature request. https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues

Answer (score 0):

The following works for me:

[image]

**Offset**

**X**

```
floor((round(@map_extent_width, 0)/ 10) + round(x_min(@map_extent),0))
```

**Y**

```
floor((round(@map_extent_height, 0)/ 10) + round(y_min(@map_extent),0))
```

*3.28.5-Firenze*