# QGIS custom grid overlapping in printing layout

Tags: qgis, print-composer, expression, grids-graticules

I've set my custom grid in the print layout. The problem is, that in one corner both values from X and Y axes overlap each other.

[image]

I used the offset, as you can see below, but I am wondering how to make this only one value offset more than the rest.

I found some similar problems here:

[Stop Grid Coordinates Overlapping in Print Layout](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/334356/stop-grid-coordinates-overlapping-in-print-layout)

which led me to the bug here:

https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/45876

My formula for custom grids looks like this:

```
CASE 
  WHEN @grid_axis = 'y'
    THEN substr('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRST', (@grid_number +105) / 100, 1) 
  WHEN @grid_axis = 'x'
    THEN round((@grid_number - 5) / 100,0)
END
```

And I obviously can change it simultaneously with the offset bringing them up, although I tried the solution, which would led offset just only the first value at the Y axis.

The formula I prepared looks like this:

```
CASE 
  WHEN @grid_axis = 'y' AND @grid_number = 'A' THEN offset = 15
END
```

but it stays as it is despite lack of error in the formula.

How can I offset only this one value separately?

Regarding my situation with interval 100 and offset 7 I tried also:

```
CASE 
  WHEN @grid_axis = 'y' AND substr('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRST', (@grid_number = 0) / 100, 1)   THEN OFFSET = 15
END
```

**UPDATE:**

I think the problem lies with the "Distance to the map frame" issue. As I set it to 5mm then the overlapping occurs. What kind of formula should I place inside then?

[image]

I could reduce the distance from the map frame, although with the font size I applied (24px) it still won't work.

[image]

Comment: How did you manage to overlap them? I cannot produce that issue.

Comment: As you can see in the panel on your right. I used primary coordinates for lines only and secondary coordinates for the labels. By adding the offset 6 for X and 7 for Y I got quite a nice placement of my labels like 10 A, 1 I, 10 I, except for 0A in the bottom left corner, which is overlapped.

Comment: Which version of QGIS are you using? I also couldn't reproduce the problem (QGIS 3.22). Perhaps the label engine has been updated. In my case the A and 0 were displaced independently of the offset so they didn't overlap.

Comment: My version is 3.12

Comment: I suggest as a test to install the latest version of QGIS and open the same project and see if this error can be reproduced. If the error disappears, it is probably a bug in an older version of QGIS.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. It's good to know, that this error is related to older versions of QGIS. I can't upgrade my QGIS right now, but I will bear it in mind for the future. The failure of given formulae application probably is also driven by the QGIS bug though.

Comment: I was be able to produce the issue. I tested in 3.22 and tried finding a solution but all attempts failed. Adding offset using expression didn't work. Adding spaces to `0` (for the first number) didn't work. I couldn't change the individual value.

Comment: So we can assume, that this is the QGIS bug. Alternatively, I can change the grid formula and display the y-axis labels from the top instead of the bottom. In turn the A letter will be at the top corner instead of the bottom corner and consecutive letters will be shifted too. Finally, I won't be able to see the I-letter which will fall outside of the map.

Comment: @KadirŞahbaz I have uploaded my question, as I realized that the problem might not come from the offset itself but from the Distance to the map frame.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some experimentation it appears that the distance to frame cannot be set independently for the X and Y axes.

Here is my label grid set up. I chose `Outside frame` for the labels so there were legible.

[image]

Using a `Distance to frame` of 5 mm and the formula:

```sql
(@grid_axis || @grid_number)
```

to show the grid axis and grid number in the label itself so there can be no confusion.

[image]

Then for `Distance to frame` I used the formula

```sql
CASE 
  WHEN @grid_axis = 'y' then 20
  WHEN @grid_axis = 'x' then 0
END
```

Both sets of labels end up at 0 mm distance.

[image]

A formula using `@grid_number`

```sql
CASE 
  WHEN @grid_number < 10 then 20.0
  ELSE 0
END
```

[image]

---

Separate note about one of your formulae

> The formula I prepared looks like this:
>
> ```
> CASE    
>    WHEN @grid_axis = 'y' AND @grid_number = 'A' 
>    THEN offset = 15 
> END
> ```
>
> but it stays as it is despite lack of error in the formula.

The `@grid_number` is never going to be `A`, so this formula, despite having no errors, will not evaluate. The `@grid_number` is always an integer and it is tied to the grid interval. The first grid square contains 100 grid numbers for each axis (1-100, 100 being your interval in mm). As seen in the image directly above, the displayed grid number for this particular set of labels is the interval `0, 100, 200, etc` + the offset `6` for the x axis and + `7` for the y axis. The rest of the grid numbes still exist, but they just have no label.